# function error() { [native code]}

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have asp.net web site in c#.

On Dropdownlist `Onchange()` event i'm calling this jquery function, which throws:

```
function error(){[native code]}

 <script type="text/javascript">
     function GetDescription(a) {
         alert(a); // the dropdown item selected value
         var id = (!isNaN($(a).val())) ? parseInt($(a).val()) : 0;
         $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             contentType: "application/json; charset-8;",
             url: 'WT.aspx/GetRef',
             data: "{ 'id':'" + id + "'}",
             success: function (data) {
                 alert(data);
             },
             error: function (data) {
                 alert(Error);
             }

         });

     }
  </script>
```

WT.aspx/GetRef

```
     [WebMethod]
     public string GetRef(int id)
     {
         DataTable dt = new DataTable();
         SqlParameter[] p = new SqlParameter[1];
         p[0] = new SqlParameter("@RefID", id);
         dt = dl.GetDataWithParameters("Sp_WT_GetRef", p);

         string data = dt.Rows[0]["Description"].ToString() +"|"+ dt.Rows[0]["PriceInUSD"].ToString();

         return data;
     }
```

> http://localhost:54576/resources/demos/style.css Failed to load
>   resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   http://localhost:54576/AutomobileWebApp/WT.aspx/GetRef Failed to load
>   resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server
>   Error) http://localhost:54576/resources/demos/style.css Failed to load
>   resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: You should look at the logs on the server side - presumably an exception is being thrown in `GetRef, but we can't tell what that is just from looking at your code.

Comment: "which throws: function error(){[native code]}". No, it doesn't throw any errors. You are just alerting a native constructor. String representation of the `Error` constructor is `function error(){[native code]}`. Use `console.log` for debugging and check the network tab of the browser developer tools to check the server response.

Comment: may be you need to mark your web method as `static` like `public static string GetRef(int id)`

Answer (score 1):

My first suggestion would be to make the method attributed as [WebMethod] to static.

```
[WebMethod]
 public static string GetRef(int id)
 {
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     SqlParameter[] p = new SqlParameter[1];
     p[0] = new SqlParameter("@RefID", id);
     dt = dl.GetDataWithParameters("Sp_WT_GetRef", p);

     string data = dt.Rows[0]["Description"].ToString() +"|"+ dt.Rows[0]["PriceInUSD"].ToString();

     return data;
 }
```

If that didn't work out, try to check whether your ajax url is pointing to the method correctly.

```
url: 'WT.aspx/GetRef',
```

and also check whether you are passing 'this' as the function parameter for GetDescription(a).

```
 <select onchange="GetDescription(this)">
    <option value="1">text1</option>
    <option value="2">text2</option>
    <option value="3">text3</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: Thank You v.much, you were right, as i did it as static, its working.

Comment: But the function GetRef(int id) its not taking that argument which i'm passing through ajax code. Can u plz help me in that...

Comment: And also its not returning the result,
success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
in alert: 'object Object' is getting instead of result.

Comment: you could get the result if you use data.d instead of data in the alert. data will always be an object so it will be alerter like "object Object". to get the specific results you need to access it through "data.d". Try "alert(data.d)"

Comment: how about the argument, its not taking that... id.. which i'm passing from ajax code.

Comment: Could you give me more information about the error you are getting. Your code worked fine when i tested it out. and make sure the parameter name for the method GetRef(int id) is same as the data passed with ajax  : `data: "{ 'id':'" + id + "'}"'